# Connecting two tables with Node.Js Express

Tags: node.js, reactjs, postgresql, express

I've looked around on the web for solutions but there doesn't seem to be an answer relevant to mine. So I would like some help on this, please. Here I have two tables I need to connect and list on the React file. game table and users table, at the moment I am only able to display game table.


Server/index.js

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const cors = require("cors");
const pool = require("./db");

//middleware
app.use(cors());
app.use(express.json()); //req.body

app.get("/af", async (req, res) => {

    try {
      const allTodos = await pool.query("SELECT game.*, users.* FROM users INNER JOIN game ON users.game_code = game.game_code;  ");
      res.json(allTodos.rows);
    } catch (err) {
      console.error(err.message);
    }
  });
```

Client/List.js

```
const List = () => {
const [af, setAF] = useState([]);
 const getTodos = async() => {
        try{
            const response = await fetch("http://localhost:5000/af");
            const jsonData = await response.json();
            setAF(jsonData);
        }catch(err){
            console.error(err.message);
        }
    }
    useEffect(() =>  {
        getTodos();
    }, []);
return(
       <Fragment>
           {" "}
       <table className="table mt-5 text-center">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>game_code</th>
        <th>user_code</th>
     </tr>
</thead>

<tbody>
         {af.map(game => (
            <tr key = {game.game}>
                <td>{game.game_code}</td>
                <td>{game.game_location}</td>
  ))} 
    </tbody>
  </table>
       </Fragment>
export default List;
```

Comment: It's really unclear what you are asking for or what is or isn't working. It looks like you query both your game and users tables and join them on game_code. You should get back a single array of data if I'm not mistaken. Is this the question? You aren't able to successfully join these two tables?

Comment: @DrewReese Sorry I'm still new at this. When I query that onto Postman, I am able to receive a [ ] array. But it has no content. I would also like to display this on my List.Js file.

Comment: Yeah, seems you need to first work out the issue with querying your DB and verifying the `allTodos` value you attempt to send in the response.